# Respostas que começam com "TL;DR" ou "TD;DR"

Tags: debate

Pra mim algumas respostas começam com `TL;DR` ou `TD;DR`. Não sei se é só aqui, mas parece um *bug*.

Veja por exemplo [esta resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2005/7261):

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquise por `TL;DR` ou `TD;DR` e você vai achar várias respostas assim:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=tl%3Bdr
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=td%3Bdr

Comment: Esse é um caso que compensava mais perguntar num comment do post do que no meta :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn't_read - Na verdade isso se usa quando você dá uma resposta muito extensa, mas põe um resumo no final. O pessoal também anda usando isso meio que "nas coxas" por aqui. Como já comentado pelo @bigown, quando é TD tem gente que interpreta assim (entre outros significados): http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=td%3Bdr

Comment: @Bacco *"Mas põe um resumo no final"* Muitas respostas não têm o tal resumo no final, são apenas longas (algumas nem tão longas).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Não é um bug, é o autor da resposta colocando um resumo do conteúdo no início. `TL;DR` é usado no SO em inglês, e quer dizer *too long, didn't read*. `TD;DR` eu não sei o que quer dizer... talvez *too dense, didn't read*?

Na prática isto quer dizer "olha, se você não tiver paciência para ler esta resposta toda, leia pelo menos esta parte aqui".

Comment: TD é Too Drunk :)

Comment: @bigown acho que se aplica em muitos casos :D http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=td%3Bdr

Comment: TD;TS [Too Drunk To Stack](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170683/stop-using-real-accounts-in-suggested-edit-audits#comment505105_170683) o.O

Comment: Bom, se esse é o caso, como estamos na SO-pt, não seria hora de criarmos nossas siglas em português? não vejo sentido em termos a SO-pt e usarmos siglas em inglês, que até agora não sabemos o significado exato...

Answer (score 14):

As respostas com `TD;DR` são minhas. Isso só significa que... meus dedos tem vícios de digitação. Já estão corrigidas as 3 respostas que estavam assim.

Nota: não bebo, então devia estar bêbado de sono.

Quanto ao `TL;DR`, comecei a usar isso enquanto acompanhava o site [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/). Embora o uso comum seja para dizer que você não leu a pergunta, a ideia é aqui adiantar a conclusão para quem não tiver paciência de ler a resposta por completo.