# O que significa OP?

Tags: suporte

Por exemplo, nas seguintes perguntas:
[Obter width total do monitor usando CSS3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23218/obter-width-total-do-monitor-usando-css3/23266#23266) , [Carregar registros de diferentes tabelas como anonymous type entity framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30802/carregar-registros-de-diferentes-tabelas-como-anonymous-type-entity-framework/30806#30806) e [O que fazer quando o O.P muda sua pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1682/o-que-fazer-quando-o-o-p-muda-sua-pergunta)
existem referências ao "OP" ou "O.P", por questão de lógica OP é uma referência ao Autor, mas qual o significado da sigla OP?

Existem outras siglas específicas do Stack Overflow em relação a perguntas?

Comment: OP vem do SOen e quer dizer "Original Poster" aqui no SOpt costumamos usar AP que quer dizer "Autor da Pergunta".

Comment: @JorgeB. as que eu deixo para você responder você responde no comentário? Francamente viu... rsrs. Recheia esse seu texto e passa logo para uma resposta.

Comment: @Math Sinta-se a vontade de responder o resto da pergunta também: Existem outras siglas específicas do Stack Overflow em relação a perguntas? :P

Comment: Hum.. Até onde eu sei não, temos siglas do tipo TL;DR mas não se limita a perguntas, e já tem uma pergunta aqui no Meta que fala sobre isso.

Comment: O OP precisa de uma resposta ao invés de comentários :P

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6311/64969

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A sigla OP vem do SOen e quer dizer "*Original Poster*", aqui no SOpt costumamos usar AP que quer dizer "Autor da Pergunta"

No Stack Overflow em Português não são usadas muitas siglas, pelo menos que eu saiba.

Eu conheço apenas:

- AP   - Autor da pergunta
- AR   - Autor da resposta
- SOpt - Stack Overflow em Português
- SOen - Stack Overflow original em Inglês.
- SE   - Stack Exchange
- CM   - *Community Manager*(Gerente de Comunidades como o [Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12/gabe))

Tem ainda algumas que transitaram do SOen para aqui como se pode ver nesta pergunta [Respostas que começam com "TL;DR" ou "TD;DR"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1641/respostas-que-come%C3%A7am-com-tldr-ou-tddr)

Por fim podes ver aqui o Dicionário do termos usados nos sites SE
[Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

Comment: No inglês, OP serve tanto para autor da pergunta e para autor da resposta, certo?

Comment: @Bacco sim, mas tenho ideia de se usa mais pra perguntas.

Comment: *"A sigla OP vem do SOen"* - Acho que poderia alterar para *"A sigla OP vem do **inglês**"*, pois não é só no SOen que se usa. Essa sigla está na internet muito antes do SOen nascer.

Comment: @EMBarbosa o uso que se dá aqui de OP vem do uso de OP no SOen. não quis dizer que nasceu lá.

Comment: Não acho que vem do uso de OP no SOen. Vem do uso da internet em geral. Mas só fiz uma sugestão, se não concordar... continuamos amigos. :D